# While building kernel image i am getting this error while doing make -j4 (Using ubuntu)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

```
lib/mpi/generic_mpih-lshift.o:/home/shubh/Root/XENO_WS/linux-3.8.13/lib/mpi/mpi-inline.h:110: first defined here
scripts/Makefile.build:443: recipe for target 'lib/mpi/mpi.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/mpi/mpi.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:454: recipe for target 'lib/mpi' failed
make[1]: *** [lib/mpi] Error 2
Makefile:791: recipe for target 'lib' failed
make: *** [lib] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

How can I resolve this? When I am doing same steps in OpenSUSE it is not giving any error. I followed these steps:

```
   make mrproper
   make oldconfig
   make -j4
```

then I get the error in between this.

Comment: Have you tried to google for error message `multiple definition of \`mpihelp_add_1'`? [Second](https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/11/9/27) and [third](https://github.com/manjaro/packages-core/issues/12) references are quite helpful. In short, check content of `lib/mpi/mpi-inline.h` file and make sure that macro *G10_MPI_INLINE_DECL* is defined as `#define G10_MPI_INLINE_DECL static inline`.

Comment: i replace the extern with static in /ib/mpi/mpi-inline.h but now it is showing some other error:-
multiple definition of `intel_gmbus_is_forced_bit'

and i have to use only linux-3.8.13 version as "third" reference is showing that it is not compatible with gcc-5

Comment: So you use gcc of version 5, which is incompatible with Linux kernel version you want to compile. Is it **allowable** for you to use lower gcc version? If so, install gcc-4.8 or gcc-4.9 and build kernel with it (there are a lot of resources which explains how to build Linux kernel with non-default compiler). If you are forced to use incompatible compiler, then google for errors you get, one by one, and try to resolve them.

Comment: It is resolve now. I build the kernel with lower version of gcc.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So you use gcc of version 5, which is incompatible with Linux kernel version you want to compile. – Tsyvarev

It is resolve now. I build the kernel with lower version of gcc. – sam1006